# complex and nested WHERE conditions in SQL with LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch posts with multiple filters, my database is as below,

"Meta" Table
[image: meta table]

"Posts" Table
[image: post table]

```
  SELECT p.id, p.title
        FROM posts p
        JOIN meta m ON p.id = m.object_id
        WHERE m.object_name='post'

        AND (m.meta_key, m.meta_value) IN (('location', 'new city'),('post_type', 'section'))
        GROUP BY p.id, p.title
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) = 2
```

I tried the above SQL and it works but trouble is if i nest more than two OR conditions with different numbers of filters i am getting wrong results.

```
just for explaining what i want , not sql :

            SELECT p.id, p.title
            FROM posts p
            JOIN meta m ON p.id = m.object_id
            WHERE m.object_name='post'
            AND
                                 (
                                    #SET 1 = (
                                       (m.meta_key = 'location' and m.meta_value = 'new city')
                                       or (m.meta_key = 'price' and m.meta_value = 100)
                                       or (m.meta_key = 'color' and m.meta_value = red)
                                    )

                                      OR

                                    #SET 2 = (
                                       m.meta_key = 'post_type' and m.meta_value = 'product'
                                       OR m.meta_key = 'location' and m.meta_value =  'delhi'
                                    )

                                 )
                          AND p.post_class='post'
              GROUP BY p.id, p.title
              HAVING if #SET 1 matched { COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) = 3 } elseIf #SET 2 matched { 
              COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) = 2 }
```

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. Simplify! [mcve].

Comment: I don't think your `#SET 2` conditions can ever be fullilled, since `m.meta_key = 'post_type'` and `m.meta_key = 'location'` cannot both be true at the same time (or maybe the `and` is supposed to be an `or` like in `#SET 1` ?)

Comment: @pepper it is supposed to be an OR , sorry i m too frustrated from morning with this, completely forgot.

Comment: @strawberry no there isn't title in both tables

Comment: @Strawberry definetly not, i just corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to have to check for each condition separately in the `having` clause.  Assuming the keys are not repeated, you can dispense with the `distinct` and use:

```
having sum( meta_key in ('location', 'price', 'color') ) = 3 or
       sum( meta_key in ('post_type', 'location') ) = 2
```

Note:  You can use `count(distinct)` for this, but I don't think it is necessary.

Comment: And to check the meta_values too: `having sum( (meta_key, meta_value) in (('location', 'new city'), ('price', 100), ('color', 'red')) ) = 3 or ... # same for set 2`

Comment: @Pepper . . . That is somewhat redundant because the `where` clause is already filtering the data.  However, it would be needed if there were duplicates and even more so if the logic involved getting more than one value per key.

Comment: I was thinking about removing those checks from the where clause entirely (but yeah, maybe at the cost of performance, not sure what the execution plan would look like)

Comment: @harshitmishra there would still be a where clause, what I had in mind would look like [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwtL5XbXETFnESCWVQYzD8/0), basically combining Gordon's idea with your first query's `(m.meta_key, m.meta_value) IN ...` clauses

Comment: @pepper looks so precise approach, it will help me understand problem with a different point of view ...

Comment: @GordonLinoff your answer helped me understand how to filter resuts further with HAVING

Comment: @Pepper i chose to do this with combination of where because i felt for my usecase it was much approachable option, also i figured that HAVING can be slow on big tables and multiple joins

Answer (score 1):

While it does nothing for performance, (I find) it can help to conceptualise this kind of problem by constructing a 'normalised' pivot of the data set, e.g.:

```
DROP TABLE my_eav;

CREATE TABLE my_eav
(entity INT NOT NULL
,attribute VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,value VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(entity,attribute)
);

INSERT INTO my_eav VALUES
(1,'location','new city'),
(1,'post_type','section'),
(1,'price','100'),
(1,'color','red'),
(2,'post_type','product'),
(2,'location','delhi');

SELECT entity
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'location' THEN value END) location
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'post_type' THEN value END) post_type
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'price' THEN value END) price
     , MAX(CASE WHEN attribute = 'color' THEN value END) color
  FROM my_eav
 GROUP 
    BY entity;
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
| entity | location | post_type | price | color |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
|      1 | new city | section   | 100   | red   |
|      2 | delhi    | product   | NULL  | NULL  |
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+-------+
```

Of course, constructing the query this way...

```
SELECT e1.entity
     , e1.value location
     , e2.value post_type
     , e3.value price
     , e4.value color
  FROM my_eav e1
  LEFT
  JOIN my_eav e2
    ON e2.entity = e1.entity
   AND e2.attribute = 'post_type'
  LEFT
  JOIN my_eav e3
    ON e3.entity = e1.entity
   AND e3.attribute = 'price'
  LEFT
  JOIN my_eav e4
    ON e4.entity = e1.entity
   AND e4.attribute = 'color'   
 WHERE e1.attribute = 'location';
```

...allows it to be transformed into a VIEW (e.g. CREATE VIEW eav_view AS...), which can then be updated - one of the few instances where a VIEW is useful...

```
UPDATE eav_view SET price = '150' WHERE price IS NOT NULL;
 Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
 Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```